# Can't Run Project on NetBeans (Ubuntu)

Tags: java, ubuntu, netbeans

OS: Ubuntu20.04

Software: NetBeans

I installed Java on my OS but I can't run my project. This is the error I get:

[image: RunProject]

Comment: Right click the project node, select "Properties", select "Run", next to the "Main Class" property, select "Browse...", select the main class you want to use.  You can also use Shift+F6 to run the current file If you prefer

Comment: Your file is in the wrong package.

Comment: Please don't post images of code or errors; see [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Your source file (`TestApp`) is located in the "default" package (root), but you have a `package` declaration of `package testapp`.

As a general rule, you shouldn't place classes in the default package.  Create a new package:

- Right click the "Source Packages" node
- Select "New > Java Package..."
- Name it `testapp`

Now move `TestApp` into this package, clean and build.

Once you're there, you can set the "main" class for the project using...

Right click on the project node (in the "Projects" explorer), select "Properties"

[image]

Select the "Run"

[image]

Next to the "Main Class" properties, select "Browse..."

[image]

and select the class you want to act as the main class.

You can also run the current file using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>

Comment: @skomisa Surprised it compiled :P

Comment: @skomisa Updated, thank you (keen eyes )